# How can i enable use of background elements when the dialog is appeared?

Tags: css, html, dojo

I created a dojo dialog using [the example](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Dialog.html) . I work with maps in background. The problem is that when the dialog is appeared, the background is blocked and i can't use the map(the dialog with no underlaying). Is there any way to enable using background when the dialog is appeard on background?

Comment: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Create-dijit-dialog-without-underlay-td2221490.html

Comment: @Era tahnks but i don't find the solution in this link

Comment: Also you can use the dojo FloatingPane, which nearly acts same as the Dialog, but without the need of manipulating the underlay. We have same Problems with the dialog and changed to Floatingpane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a little hack :

```js
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/DialogUnderlay", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog, DialogUnderlay){
    //just for the snippets to get the right styling
    document.body.className = "tundra";
  
  
    myDialog = new Dialog({
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 300px"
    });
  
    myDialog2 = new Dialog({
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 300px"
    });
  
    showDialog2 = function () {
       myDialog2.show().then(function() {
            DialogUnderlay.hide()
            //little hack to avoid JS error when closing the dialog
            DialogUnderlay._singleton.bgIframe = {destroy: function() {}} 
       });
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"> 

<button onclick="myDialog.show();">show with underlay</button>

<button onclick="showDialog2();">show without underlay</button>
```

Comment: Thanks . Thats it . I have another question. I have some buttons that i want to locate in the dialog. the buttons are created declerative. How do i locate the buttons in the dialogs? is there any way to assign the buttons to content? or using dojo.byID?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289711/how-to-locate-buttons-in-a-dojo-dialog